# Google Analytics Request URI to Event advanced filter

Tags: google-analytics

I have a query string attached to a Request URI.

Whilst I can see this data within the pages report and it works, I was thinking about setting up an advanced filter to convert the request URI to an Event, with the hope this would clean up my pages report and sit this query with related events in my data.

I can see in advanced filters that this is possible, but seems limited to specifying a single event area, so Cat, action or Label, not all 3.

Does any one know how I could set up an advanced filter to find any URIs that contain a specific query string, say example below.

```
www.example.com?querystring=123
```

and convert this into an event, where I can set the Cat, action and label.

Answer (score 1):

Is the "querystring" parameter the result of a visitor using the search functionality on your site? If so, you can setup site search tracking within the admin console. Go to your view > site search settings and add `?`. Alternatively, you could exclude the URL query parameter all together by adding querystring.